# Python - Defining a variable without initializing, but with a value

Tags: variables, initialization

I'm working on a small task from the checkio-python coding game. It involves hard-scripting the built-in functions min() and max().

Anyway to "store" the minimal or maximal value, I thought of initializing a variable first and then store the respective lowest or highest value in it.

```
min_value = None

...function to compare element 1 with element 2 of a list and find lowest..

min_value = lowest_value

...function continues
```

When I realized that I had forgotten to compare the min_value with the lowest_value, to make sure that I would have the "globally" lowest value (of the whole list). But when I compare it, it gives me a NoneError with the first initialized variable.

```
 min_value = None

...function to compare element 1 with element 2 and find lowest..
if lowest_value < min_value:
    NoneError
```

So how could I initialize a value without a value, which has in this case also the highest possible value, which then would change after the first comparison.

I hope, I that I was able to make my question clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depend of the type of the value.

For a int, then use:

```
min_value = sys.maxsize
```

For a float, then use:

```
min_value = float('inf')
```

So any values will be smaller than those maximal numbers.

---

Alternatively, you can define the initial value with the first value of your list and iterate the list from the second value.

```
min_value = list[0]
for value in list[1:]:
    if value < min_value:
        min_value = value
```

This has the advantage to work with any type.

---

Even more alternatively, you can reduce a lambda expression like this:

```
min_value = reduce(lambda min_value, value: min_value if (min_value < value) else value, list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead in initializing them as `None`, you can initialize them with a maximum/minimum integer value:

```
import sys
min_value = sys.maxsize
max_value = -sys.maxsize
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure that you are not comparing to None:

```
mylist = [2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8]
min_value = None
for num in mylist:
    if min_value is not None and num > min_value:
        continue
    else:
        min_value = num

print "Minimum value: {0}".format(min_value)
```

Produces:

```
Minimum value: 2
```